# VS Code remote connection out of memory in AWS EC2 Ubuntu 16.04 64bit

Tags: amazon-web-services, memory, visual-studio-code

I use VS code remote to access an AWS EC2 ubuntu 16 instance. The server started to freeze.

Using the screes shots provided by AWS, I found that the reason for freeze is out of memory and it marked two processes.

On the log, it's clear that 2 processes are both have something to do with VS code.

How am I supposed to do to fix this?

[Screen shot of instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6JxO.jpg)

[Log of processes before freeze](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9WDG.jpg)

Comment: how many RAM did you allocate for your virtual machine? VSCode remote required at least 4GB

Answer (score 2):

I Know its a long time since you asked this question, but the problem lies within the vscode. Its not linux/AWS/EC2/Your fault. I know it doesn't really solve your problem, but try not to use VSCode ssh untill the problem is fixed. It is crashing even servers with 128GB of ram